# generate special character ö with shortcut in vim

Tags: vim, remap

I want to press `CTRL-;` to generate the special character `ö`. I have tried to write this line in my `.vimrc`

```
inoremap <C-;> <C-K>o:
```

but nothing happens when I press CTRL-;. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `vim` or `gvim`? In `vim` that mapping will hardly work — terminals don't have charcter `<C-;>`. Should work in `gvim` — works for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have `ö`, why not use it directly?

```
inoremap <key> ö
```

Anyway, the core issue, here, is that the control character `^;` doesn't exist. This means that TUI Vim, which cares about characters, not keys, can't see that `Ctrl+;` you pressed and thus can't do whatever you mapped to `<C-;>`.

I would suggest you find another mapping.

Comment: but it still does not work, when I use this mapping `inoremap CTRL-L; ö` all that appears is `^L`

Comment: That doesn't look like a Vim mapping at all.

Comment: This works as expected for me:  `inoremap <C-L> <C-k>o:`